# Can you send click events to another application?

Tags: android

I'm trying to send click events from one application (or service) to another application while it's in the background.

I've learned about the ability to send Intents to other applications. I was able to send an id, that represented a view id inside the receiving android application, and have the receiving application handle the click event. But I'm trying to accomplish this with a receiving application that I have no control of (can't setup intent filters, etc). I understand the security risks with this, but I'm just trying to achieve it for a quick demo, not an actual application.

Is this possible? Maybe on a rooted device?

Comment: On a rooted device, perhaps. Definitely not on a non-rooted device, for obvious security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

There are automated Android testing frameworks which allow you to test both white-box within your own code, as well as black-box on other applications. Unfortunately I haven't gotten the chance to try automated testing on an outside app, but presumably you would be able to simulate click events in the same way that you can within your own application.

Perhaps this would be something to look into?

http://robotium.googlecode.com/svn-history/r376/doc/com/jayway/android/robotium/solo/Solo.html#clickOnView(android.view.View)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have looked into the testing frameworks but they all require the application to be in the foreground.